# Analog motion triggered alarm design (amateur) - Seeking professional's advice

Tags: circuit-design, analog, timer, battery-operated, diy

I've designed a circuit and I want to confirm if it will work. Below is the working:

A very low current, battery powered motion alarm.

1. User can set 3 timers (srm delay, alarm go off delay, alarm duration). Arm delay is the delay after the device is turned on, alarm go off delay is the delay between motion detection and alarm ringing, duration of alarm is self explanatory.
2. I didn't use a microcontroller as this is a simple application. Also, this way it costs less money and uses less current, actually the only thing that consumes current at idle state is the sensor (except nanoamps that leak through semiconductors) and literally nothing else. If there was Arduino it would consume current too (even in sleep mode consumes more than than the sensor).
3. The sensor and the alarm will be in separate places. The sensor itself will be at a balcony whereas the alarm will be inside, behind an iron door, so that even when the sensor is broken by the intruder, the alarm can operate. That's why I built a circuit so that the sensor fills a capacitor and even if it dies the capacitor continues to trigger the alarm.

Part1:

[image: left side of the circuit]

9V DC adapter can be left on the device or plugged out. There is a battery protection circuit with batteries but it is not shown in the schematic. To turn on the device, a 3-position switch is moved form 0 to 1 and it closes SW1 and SW3. This causes the sensor to be active so that user can test how sensitive the sensor is without triggering the alarm. Sensor gives 3.3 V from data line when motion is detected otherwise its 0 V (D5 LED turns on when sensor detects something). Also SW3 charges C7 quickly to 5 V and C7 keeps MOSFET Q9 on (even though there is no flow between drain and source yet). When the switch is turned from 1 to 2, SW2 closes and SW3 opens, the relay gets activated and prevents any motion detection reach Q3; this is the time where the users leaves the room without triggering the alarm themselves. After C7 is discharged the system goes into armed mode. The best thing is there is no power consumption besides the sensor. If motion is detected from now on, Q3 turns on and charges C5. In part 2 lets see what this capacitor will trigger.

Part 2:
[image: right side of the circuit]

C5 triggers Q1 and so the U4 buck converter will start, also C2 will start charging; charging rate can be controlled by alarm delay trimpot. When the capacitor is charged to more than 3.7 V U2:A will send a signal to trigger the alarm. The signal turns on Q6 and C6, which is responsible for alarm duration, starts to charge, until it is charged to 3.7 V the alarm will ring. Also, the LM2587 boost converter is activated to ring the alarm and power the LED, and the 555 timer is activated and blinks an LED. The high voltage part is isolated with optocouplers (I burned an Arduino regulator when I didn't use optocouplers so I am cautious this time). When C6 is charged, U2:B turns on Q7 and discharges C5. When C5 is discharged the alarm will turn off. If C4 wasn't there, C5 would discharge just enough to turn off Q1 and that may create instability; that's why C4 keeps discharging C5 for some more time. As C5 discharges, C2 and C6 also discharge from the diodes to reset their timers. After that, the alarm goes to armed state until it is triggered again.

The story was so long I know, I would like to get design recommendations or my mistakes pointed out. I couldn't add a clock with oscillator pulses because I don't how to effectively count them and give output depending on the number. I used capacitors instead and so many transistors. My perspective for electronics is still narrow and I would like to expand it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are other MCU boards besides Arduino. The Texas Instruments MSP430 series is designed for low-power applications. MSP430G2553 and MSP430FR5994 are popular low-end low-power MCUs. Your design is how someone might have done it 40 years ago.

Comment: Exactly, my method is for boomers. But why did people quit doing pure analog designs, I find it so authentic. I'll consider that option.